# How to get the id of selected radio button in Razor code?

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have three radio buttons on my HTML form i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn1" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn2" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn3" />
```

I want to see which radio button is selected so that I can further process. I am trying this

```
@functions{
    var choice = Request.Params["radioBtn"];
}
```

But the "choice" only returns 'on'. How can I know which one of these radio buttons are actually active at this point of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your radio buttons aren't in any way different from one another, as far as the form is concerned.  Give them values:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn1" value="rdBtn1" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn2" value="rdBtn2" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="rdBtn3" value="rdBtn3" />
```

That way the form can post more than just the binary option of whether or not the radio button was selected.  Then `choice` should end up with the `value` of the one which was selected.